# Flash fails to load:

Tags: flash, null, load, buffer, unity-game-engine

I've built a `Flash` - file using `Unity3D`. The Flash file occasionally fails to load onto a web page. This behavior has been sporadic between the web browsers and operating systems. For example, I have only seen this behavior using `Google Chrome` on a `Mac`. Other reports claim this activity occurs throughout different browsers on `Windows`. I'm wondering if this is an internal error.

On the top left-hand corner of the view area, I receive a `Fatal error: "null" in a red background`.

Feedback from the Flash Player Content Debugger displayed all of this:

```
Fatal Error : ArgumentError: Error #3672: Buffer creation failed. Internal error.
at flash.display3D::Context3D/createVertexBuffer()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/Ext_Stage3D_Create_VertexBuffer()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN14GfxMolehillVBO16UpdateVertexDataERK16VertexBufferData()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN4Mesh15CreateSharedVBOEm()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN4Mesh12GetSharedVBOEm()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN8DrawUtil11DrawMeshRawERKN9ShaderLab14ChannelAssignsER4Meshi()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZThn28_N12MeshRenderer6RenderEiRKN9ShaderLab14ChannelAssignsE()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN13BatchRenderer5FlushEv()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_Z25DoForwardShaderRenderLoopR23ForwardShaderRenderLoopR17RenderLoopContextR13dynamic_arrayI16RenderObjectDataLj4EL18MemLabelIdentifier52EEbbP13RenderTextureb()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_Z12DoRenderLoopR10RenderLoop13RenderingPathRSt6vectorI11VisibleNodeSaIS3_EEbP6ShaderRKSs()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN6Camera6RenderEiP6ShaderRKSs()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN13RenderManager13RenderCamerasEv()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/NativeExt_PlayerLoop()
at com.unity::UnityContentInternal/playerLoop()
at com.unity::UnityContent/onEnterFrame()
```

A load later provided this feedback:

```
Fatal Error : Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.
at flash.utils::ByteArray/set length()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/sbrk()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/malloc()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN21UnityDefaultAllocatorI17LowLevelAllocatorE8AllocateEji()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN13MemoryManager8AllocateEji10MemLabelIdiPKci()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_Z15malloc_internalji10MemLabelIdiPKci()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN9Texture2D8TransferI18StreamedBinaryReadILb0EEEEvRT_()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN9Texture2D23VirtualRedirectTransferER18StreamedBinaryReadILb0EE()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN14SerializedFile10ReadObjectEli18ObjectCreationModebPP8TypeTreePbPP6Object()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN17PersistentManager26LoadFileCompletelyThreadedERKSsPlS2_ibP12LoadProgress()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN21PreloadLevelOperation7PerformEv()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN14PreloadManager26UpdatePreloadingSingleStepEb()
at com.unity::UnityNative$/NativeExt_LoadFirstLevel()
at com.unity::UnityContentInternal/loadFirstLevel()
at com.unity::UnityContent/onFrameInitStep()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After receiving a different area, I realize my `Flash` file is a **big memory hog**. I've narrowed the root of my problem down to a texture problem. 
In my case, there were several textures making a 3D sphere, each being approximately 2MB in size. I compressed each texture to under 100KB.

Comment: If you find out this is the actual cause, you might want to accept your own answer as the correct one just to help the future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Budwiser. I'm about 80% positive on this solution. I know the "where" part. I haven't been able to fully identify the "what", "how" and "why" parts, if that makes sense.